# Get XML node using XMLNode(.Net) with multiple condition

Tags: asp.net, xml, xmlnode

My XML format is like this.

```
<Rule id="MyRule">
      <SubRule type="min" id="50" />
</Rule>
```

I wrote the path to get the every nodes which ***id*** is greater than equal ***50***

```
Rule[@id='MyRule']/subrule[@type='min' and @id>='50']
```

But I didn't get what I wanted, it just returned all nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following (changing the case on SubRule and the string comparison) ?

```
Rule[@id='MyRule']/SubRule[@type='min' and compare(@id,'50')>=0]
```

Are all your numbers two digits ? ( I guess '7' > '50', '100' < '50'  )

If you just want to compare numbers, you may try

```
Rule[@id='MyRule']/SubRule[@type='min' and number(@id)>=50]
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer but I got confuse in this. All I want is I want to get the nodes those @id are greater than 50.

Comment: @kst just completed my answer